# Group Theory - find left cosets

Tags: group-theory

Let $s$ be the reflection in $D_6$ with respect to the vertices $1$ and $4$ and let $r$ be rotation by $\dfrac{2\pi}{6}$. Write down the cosets of $H=\left\langle s,r^2\right\rangle$.

If $H=\langle s\rangle$ or something with just one element I'd be able to find the cosets but with two I'm not really sure. I'm not even really sure what $\left\langle s,r^2\right\rangle$ or the element $(s,r^2)$ is.

EDIT: I think $\left\langle s,r^2\right\rangle=\{(s,r^2),(s^2,r^4),(s^3,r^6),(s^4,r^2),(s^5,r^4),e\}$ but don't know what to do with it

Comment: What are your efforts at solving the problem? Posts which simply have the tone "Solve this problem for me" are likely to attract downvotes. Having said that let me tell you the meaning of $<s,r^2>$, it is the smallest subgroup containing those 2 elements. List out those elements. The group itself has only 12 elements. You can try brute force at least.

Comment: I'm sorry. I just edited my question to include what I think $<s,r^2>$ is. I know that $s$ on it's own is just a reflection, and $r$ on it's own is a rotation, but what is $(s,r^2)$ put together like this?

Comment: If $s$ is a reflection you should find out  what $s^2$ is. Figure this out  before attempting anything else.

Comment: $\left\langle s,r^2\right\rangle$ is the set of all elements of finite _products_ of $s$ and $r^2$ (and their inverses). So, e.g., the elements $sr^2$ and $sr^4$ are in $\left\langle s,r^2\right\rangle$, as is $s^2r^2$ = .... .

Comment: How do you know to multiply $s$ and $r^2$ together? Does it have anything to do with the direct product?

Comment: One definition of $\left\langle s,r^2\right\rangle$ is that it is the smallest subgroup of $D_6$ containing $s$ and $r^2$. Since groups are closed under the group operation, which here is composition of the symmetries, the subgroup $\left\langle s,r^2\right\rangle$ must also contain their composition $sr^2$. I termed this composition the _product_ of $s$ and $r^2$ in my previous comment, perhaps confusingly.

Comment: Okay got it, thanks!